# google map given error unfortunatley googlemap has stopped

Tags: android

I am design a Google map in android , I have add Google map service lib,layout

```
 <fragment  
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
           />
```

Main Activity  is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


         mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
        Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title("My Office"));
          }
   }
```

Manifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <permission
        android:name="maping.amit.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

       <uses-permission android:name="maping.amit.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my keys are there ....."/>
```

Comment: <permission
    android:name="maping.amit.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 
 <uses-permission android:name="maping.amit.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
 <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

Comment: unfortunatley map has stopped

Comment: 01-25 09:55:15.199: W/dalvikvm(15823): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ddd438)

Comment: Sending signal. PID: 16612 SIG: 9

Comment: dalvikvm logcot message threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ddd438) pid=19922

Answer (score 0):

Providing the link follow where you can get the [map](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

and for marking your location you this code

```
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = 17.385044;
double longitude = 78.486671;

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

// Changing marker icon
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
        Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title("My Office")); try to block those lines and execute that code ..

Comment: log cot error is :-threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ddd438)